# Which band had the last music video before CGI effects?

Tags: music-video, pop

My suggestion is "Fascination" by Human League. Yes that paint in the video is real paint! That was 1983. But I would be fascinated to be wrong.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think it's unanswerable.  There wasn't a hard line between pre-CGI and post-CGI (in the world of music videos or beyond).

Comment: It's also worth noting that CGI was first used commercially [as early as 1970](https://web.archive.org/web/20160806054253/http://design.osu.edu/carlson/history/lesson2.html) (13 years before "Fascination"), so much of the history of music videos takes place after CGI was already in use.